# symfony5 apache : I see file in browser, doesnt execute code

Tags: apache, production, symfony5

I've tried several things but not possible to configure properly symfony5 with apache webserver in production.

What I see when I enter http://example.com is this:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

What am I missing?

I think it's a simple point, but can't catch it.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you must change the .htaccses to point to /public folder not the project folder
you could validate and get more information [Configuring a Web Server for symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)